# SCSS function remains uncompiled in CSS output

Tags: sass

Seems like I must have some syntax error with my function?

Defined as so:

```
@function v($i, $a: $ba) {
$ca: $i*$a;

$x: $r*(sin($ca) + $p*sin($q*$ca));
$y: $r*(cos($ca) - $p*cos($q*$ca));
$z: $r*sin(($q + 1)*$ca);

@return $x, $y, $z;
}
```

in my output style.css document I still see the function calls:

```
--v: v($i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to use [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____) where you call your function:

```
.selector {
  --v: #{v($i)};
}
```

Comment: Any time Daniel. I myself find the necessity of interpolation puzzling in Sass, or more like when it is necessary. You need to use interpolation in strings, such as a `::before` `content`, also, if I am not mistaken, within CSS functions, such as `calc()`. In your case, I think the value of your CSS variable might be treated as a string, hence the necessity of interpolation, but this is just a guess.